# sitemap on a website only shows one link

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a little issue concerning the sitemap of a website.

The website is : http://parmemarin.com.

If I go on http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and try to generate a sitemap for my website I end up with only one link in my sitemap which is _inc/conditions.php

There is no index.php or other of my links (index.php?page=...)

Can someone help me on this one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, for your answer.

I had totally forgot to delete the meta : no index, no follow ... That clearly didn't helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that could be a problem with xml-sitemaps.com, it could be a problem with your site, or it could be a combination of both. I don't know that service, so I can't tell how it really works and what it does.

Skimming through your markup, I noticed that you linked to some URLs without encoding the ampersand. `&` (if used for parameters) should be `&amp;` if you link it in HTML.

I wonder: Why don't you build your sitemap yourself? You are the only one who knows for sure which pages exist on your site. Collect all your URLs and put them in a file, like http://www.sitemaps.org/ describes.